# Cant get request from JsonArray Request

Tags: android, json, request, jsonparser

I want to make a request to an api using jsonarrayrequest. I want then o get the data and use it on an adapter, but since I get nothing, my adapter gives me an error in the getITemCount, since there is not List for the size method. I do this in onCreate of the activity, a fragment, where I want to get the data. This fragment has a recycleView and is used into a pageviewer.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SingletonDicas.getInstance(getContext()).setDicasListener(this);
    SingletonDicas.getInstance(getContext()).getAllDicasAPI(getActivity(), DicaJsonParser.isConnectionInternet(getActivity()), "Receitas");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dicas, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewDicas);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));

    adapter_dicas = new Adapter_Dicas(dicasListAlimentacao);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_dicas);
}

    }
```

This is my getAllDicas method and my setDicasListener, inside of a singleton. I cant find why, but in the first method, it will go only until the first System.out.println, it never goes through the actual request, just "jumps" out.

```
public static synchronized SingletonDicas getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE == null){

        INSTANCE =  new SingletonDicas(context);
        volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public void getAllDicasAPI(final Context context, boolean isConnected, final String type){

    System.out.println("--> isconnected : " + isConnected);

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, mUrlAPIDicas, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    dicas = DicaJsonParser.parserJsonDicas(response, context, type);

                    adicionarDicasBD(dicas);

                    if(dicasListener != null)
                    {
                        dicasListener.onRefreshListaDicas(dicas);
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                    System.out.println("--> Erro: ");

                }
            });
    volleyQueue.add(req);
}

public void setDicasListener(DicasListener dicasListener)
{
    this.dicasListener = dicasListener;
}
```

My DicasJsonParser:

```
public class DicaJsonParser {

    public static ArrayList<Dica> parserJsonDicas(JSONArray response, Context contexto, String type) {
        System.out.println("--> PARSER LISTA DICAS: " + response.toString());
        ArrayList<Dica> tempListaDicas = new ArrayList<Dica>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject dica = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                int idDica = dica.getInt("Id");
                String channelDica = dica.getString("Channel");
                String tituloDica = dica.getString("Title");
                String conteudoDica = dica.getString("Content");

                if(dica.getString("Channel").equals(type))
                {
                    Dica auxDica = new Dica(idDica,channelDica,tituloDica,conteudoDica);
                    tempListaDicas.add(auxDica);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return tempListaDicas;
    }

    public static boolean isConnectionInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like, nothing wrong in this code bro. Try putting debugger in onResponse and onErrorResponse.

Comment: I tried but it never gets there. If I put a system.out after 'JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest...' it wont show, neither on the 'Response.ErrorListener'

Comment: if you call the URL manually does it work?

Comment: then your volley queue could be improperly configured, can provide more code there

Comment: @joao86 it should atleast go to onResponseError in any case

Comment: @AmitKaushik it should but I can't see what is wrong with the code, so it does not hurt to ask :)

Comment: Im sorry, with the debug mode it does go in the Request but jumps out, but I cant it to get into the error. Tried with the URL manually, same result. Added the code to the volley queue.

Comment: @NelsonSilva if you call the API in the browser does it show the expected result?

Comment: @joao86 yes it does work properly

Comment: Your singleton implementation looks very problematic, please keep volleyQueue as field and not static variable in your singleton and instantiate it in constructor.

Comment: @AmitKaushik Ok I added volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context); to my singletonDicas constructor and is no longer private, but I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`
public class SingletonDicas {

```
private static SingletonDicas singletonDicas;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private SingletonDicas(Context applicationContext) {
    this.requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);
}

public static SingletonDicas getInstance(Context applicationContext) {
    if (singletonDicas == null) {
        synchronized (SingletonDicas.class) {
            if (singletonDicas == null) {
                singletonDicas = new SingletonDicas(applicationContext);
            }
        }
    }
    return singletonDicas;
}
```

}
`

try this implementation of singleton...I think implementation is problem.

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting the same error:
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: please use Log.d("NelsonProblem--",msg) for logging and attach the logcatlog after filtering with tag("NelsonProblem--").

Comment: where is `I want then o get the data and use it on an adapter, but since I get nothing, my adapter gives me an error in the getITemCount, since there is not List for the size method. ` this code?

Comment: This code(`adapter_dicas = new Adapter_Dicas(dicasListAlimentacao); recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_dicas);`) can only be inside `onRefreshListaDicas(dicasList)`

Comment: I sse, but when I run the app for the first time, I get no error but also no data. When I change the page in the page viwer, I can see that Im getting some data but I get the same error about the null object, cant call size().